# how would I use public classes to transfer data from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android

I tried creating a public class to try transferring data from one activity to another. But when I tried setting the information of this class altogether I manage to get the Int variables but not the String and when I tried to get this data it was blank.

This is My MainActivity

```
public void toyota_yaris(View view) {
        CurrentCar currentcar = new CurrentCar();
        currentcar.setInfo("Toyota Yaris",130,8,1160,7);


        Intent switchScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CarActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(switchScreen);
    }
```

This is My CarActivity

```
CurrentCar currentcar = new CurrentCar();

TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setText(currentcar.getName());

TextView speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
speed.setText(String.valueOf(currentcar.getSpeed()));
```

This is My CurrentCar Class (getter and setter class)

```
public class CurrentCar {
    private String mName;
    private int mSpeed;
    private int mAge;
    private int mMileage;
    private int mSeats;

    public void setInfo(String Name,int Speed,int Age,int Mileage,int Seats ) {
        mName = Name;
        mSpeed = Speed;
        mAge = Age;
        mMileage = Mileage;
        mSeats = Seats;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
    public int getSpeed() {
        return mSpeed;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return mAge;
    }
    public int getMileage() {
        return mMileage;
    }
    public int getSeats() {
        return mSeats;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Singleton to make your CurrentCar class static and visible to CarActivity. Or you can implement parcelable to pass your car object between activities. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data from one activity to another , then attach it with intents.
Example-

In MainActivity-

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "A");
bundle.putString("speed", "100"); 

Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,CarActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In carActivity-

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
String name=bundle.getString("name");
String speed=bundle.getString("speed");
```

and then set these values in text views.

Answer (score 0):

in **My CarActivity** you are creating new Object : `CurrentCar currentcar = new CurrentCar();`

so if you call `name.setText(currentcar.getName());`  then it will simply return null because strings default is null.

just use the object being created in **My MainActivity**